# How to change TimerHandler delay in AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have this method i create that adds a sprite to my andengine scene every second.

```
 private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler(){
        TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
        float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;
        spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true,new ITimerCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                addFace();
        }
        });
        getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
}
```

What i want to do is, for example

```
if(x <= b){

 mEffectSpawnDelay = mEffectSpawnDely - .2f;
 }
```

The problem i am running into is that when the variable is changed. I cant figure out a way to update the TimeHandler letting it know to change the mEffectSpawnDelay variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do it the way you want to. What you need is a way of telling the TimerHandler that the spawn delay changed. You'll have to look in the API whether a method exists that can do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created [this class](http://pastebin.com/Rf8DWGv4) just now for you. I think it should work, and you can change the interval between ticks as you wish. (Haven't tested it, so you might need to make some small fixes. But it looks fine IMO.)

Use it this way:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(interval, new Timer.ITimerCallback() {
    public void onTick() {
        //Your code to execute each interval.
    }
}
(Engine object here).registerUpdateHandler(timer);
```

If you ever want to change the interval, you should keep a reference to the timer. Anyways, to change interval use:

```
timer.setInterval(newInterval);
```

Comment: Nicee...Could you put an edit in the answer on how to implement this with what i want to do? Thanks alot thats awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Store the handler in an instance variable, and call its `setTimerSeconds` method when needed.

Comment: There is no setTimerSeconds method on TimeHandler.

Comment: There is one here: http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/engine/handler/timer/TimerHandler.java?spec=svn122487e74fa1fdad6cb79d4cbc9e22faf7b6f6ca&r=122487e74fa1fdad6cb79d4cbc9e22faf7b6f6ca.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the TimerHandler source file here: http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/handler/timer/TimerHandler.java?r=30ba07312ed7d4636077b835ba15f772e3f30db7

You'll see that there isn't a method to update the interval. And the variable `mTimerSeconds` is also final.

I would implement my own `IUpdateHandler` class and add a non-final `mTimerSeconds` and a method to update it.

You can copy the existing TimerHandler and then make the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Override onCreateEngine method with new FixedStepEngine

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {

    return new FixedStepEngine(pEngineOptions, 30);
}
```