# Android AndEngine RegisterUpdateHandler variable time

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using andengine and I have something like this:

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(anotherclass.getSpeed(), true,
            new ITimerCallback() {
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            //Something I need done
        }
    }));
```

The thing is `getSpeed()` returns first time let's say 0.20f . Then `getspeed` would return 0.18f but I think that it is called only once when the timer is started and even though my speed from the other class changes, my timer runs at the interval `init_speed`.

So, I need a way to dynamically change the time period of the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was asked once before, and I created a timer class in which you can change the interval as you want. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271473/how-to-change-timerhandler-delay-in-andengine/8273177#8273177) is the question, and [here](http://pastebin.com/Rf8DWGv4) is the timer class.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1f, new ITimerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTick() {
        //Do what you need here.
    }
}
```

Register it:

```
(Engine/Entity/Scene here).registerUpdateHandler(timer);
```

Now, save the reference to the timer. Whenever you want to change the interval, just call `setInterval` and the interval will be changed.

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out from that example so I just used Java util.Timer class instead.

Comment: I can give you an example if you need one. Using java.util.Timer object may lead to the creation of another thread, which will just slow down your app... AndEngine timer runs on existing thread, it is a better option.

Comment: Hm. An example would be great. I created the timer using your timer class but it still had fixed rate repetitions. I tryed to use setIntervals but still didn't work. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {

    return new FixedStepEngine(pEngineOptions, 30);
}
```